# How to kill this immortal nginx worker?

Tags: linux, nginx, admin

I have started nginx and when I stop like root

```
/etc/init.d/nginx stop
```

after that I type

```
ps aux | grep nginx
```

and get response like `tcp LISTEN 2124 nginx WORKER`

```
kill -9 2124  # tried with kill -QUIT 2124, kill -KILL 2124
```

and after I type again

```
ps aux | grep nginx
```

and get response like `tcp LISTEN 2125 nginx WORKER`
and so on.

How to kill this immortal Chuck Norris worker ?

Comment: I know this is silly, but did you try `sudo service nginx stop` ?

Comment: In my case i had no nginx installed, gitlab was responsible to spawn the workers.

Comment: Have you tried disable from systemd?
`systemctl disable nginx.service` and try to `kill -9 PID`.
Thats work for me

Answer (score 6):

After `kill -9` there's nothing more to do to the process - it's dead (or doomed to die).  The reason it sticks around is because either (a) it's parent process hasn't waited for it yet, so the kernel holds the process table entry to keep it's status until the parent does so, or (b) the process is stuck on a system call into the kernel that is not finishing (which usually means a buggy driver and/or hardware).

If the first case, getting the parent to wait for the child, or terminating the parent, should work.  Most programs don't have a clear way to make them "wait for a child", so that may not be an option.

In the second case, the most likely solution is to reboot.  There may be tools that could clear such a condition, but that's not common.  Depending on just what that kernel processing is doing, it may be possible to get it to unblock by other means - but that requires knowledge of that processing.  For example, if the process is blocked on a kernel lock that some other process is somehow holding indefinitely, terminating that other process could aleviate the problem.

Note that the `ps` command can distinguish these two states as well.  These show up in the 'Z' state.  See the ps man page for more info: http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps.  They may also show up with the text "defunct".

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.
In my case gitlab was the responsible to bring the nginx workers.
when i completelly removed gitlab from my server i got able to kill the nginx workers.

> 1. `ps -aux | grep "nginx"`
> 2. Search for the workers and check at the first column who is bringing them up.
> 3. kill or unistall the responsible and kill the workers again, they will stop spawning ;D

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue.

Check if you are using any auto-healer like Monit or Supervisor which runs the worker whenever you try to stop them. If Yes Disable them.

My workers were being spawned due to changes I forget i made in update-rc.d in Ubuntu.

So I installed [sysv-rc-conf](http://sysv-rc-conf.sourceforge.net/) which gives a clean interface control of what processes are on reboot, you can disable from there and I assure you no Chuck Noris Resurrection :D